# Restrict a user from creating table in a database in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Using sql authorization in hive, how do I restrict a user from creating tables in a database?

After adding any user in hadoop , the user was able to create tables in hive databases, like the one below. So is there a way to restrict users from creating tables in hive databases.

```
useradd test001

beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://master01.teradata.com:10000' -n test001  -p test001

create table table01 (col1 int) ;
insert into table01 values (1);
select * from table01;
1 row selected (0.309 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

see [Grant/Revoke Privileges](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Default+Authorization+-+Legacy+Mode#HiveDefaultAuthorization-LegacyMode-Grant/RevokePrivileges)

**try:**

```
> revoke create on Database <db_Name> from user test001;
```

---

**syntax:**

```
GRANT
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    [ON object_specification]
    TO principal_specification [, principal_specification] ...
    [WITH GRANT OPTION]

REVOKE [GRANT OPTION FOR]
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    [ON object_specification]
    FROM principal_specification [, principal_specification] ...

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION
    FROM user [, user] ...

priv_type:
    ALL | ALTER | UPDATE | CREATE | DROP
  | INDEX | LOCK | SELECT | SHOW_DATABASE 

object_specification:
    TABLE tbl_name
  | DATABASE db_name

principal_specification:
    USER user
  | GROUP group
  | ROLE role
```